# NSIS Reboot in silent mode. How to communicate?

Tags: windows, nsis, reboot

we have software which we build with nsis installer. At one point, regarding of some conditions we need to do a restart or not.

This is not a problem. We do it like:

```
;Reboot instructions. In silent mode just set a RebootFlag and otherwize show the confirmation box.
IfRebootFlag doReboot doNotReboot
doReboot:
    IfSilent doSilent doNotSilent 
    doSilent:
        ;if silent, do not reboot
        Goto doNotReboot
    doNotSilent:
        MessageBox MB_YESNO "A reboot is required to finish the installation. Do you wish to reboot now?" IDNO doNotReboot
            Reboot
doNotReboot:
```

When the software is installed by software distribution through our administrators (and not by user directly and not silent), they need to know if a restart is needed.

What would be a good way to let them know and why?

We have currently two options.

1. Write a Registry Key. Is there a standard way for this in Windows or a key which already there for this purpose?`
2. Return a defined return code. Also here, is there a standard?

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MsiExec.exe uses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376931(v=vs.85).aspx) [`ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681386(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED). You can set the exit code in NSIS with [`SetErrorLevel`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#seterrorlevel):

```
!ifndef ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED
!define ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED 3010
!endif

Section
IfRebootFlag ...
  ...
  SetErrorLevel ${ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you it helped .. Apparently I did not researched properly.